# Neatly centering a div between one floated left and one floated right

Tags: html, css, css-float

If I have a div which I want to center between two other divs, one floated left and one floated right, giving it a margin of exactly 10 pixels on either side (between it and the div on that side), how would I give it a fluid width, such that it would get wider or narrower as the window size is changed, but always maintain a distance of exactly 10 pixels between it and the divs on either side?

Comment: Are the left and right divs of a fixed width?

Comment: Yes, but they are also fixed.

Comment: I don't think its possible with pure CSS, you might have to resort to Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9H9C/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div id=wrapper>
  <div id=leftdiv>left</div>
  <div id=rightdiv>right</div>
  <div id=main>
    Lorum Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {
  padding-right:60px;
  padding-left:60px;

}
#leftdiv {
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
#rightdiv {
  float:right;
  width:50px;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
```

Comment: If `background-color` is applied to `#main`, you can see that the center div isn't exactly "centered"
http://jsfiddle.net/b9H9C/3/

Comment: Quite so. I've removed the redundant `width:100%` from the `#main` rule and updated the answer and the fiddle.

Comment: Haven't tested but seems right.  Only comments are may need to set z-index greater on sides, and set main div to box-sizing: border-box.  Then you could probably use the 100% property again.  Given you are using a fluid layout, you may want to make sure child divs inside main can have a relative base.

Comment: Woops, if you use border-box, then you will have to set side divs to absolute positioning and left:0px right:0px respectively.  Better to not use box-sizing property unless you use it on an inner div for main.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle of my answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/utThB/

If your left and right `div` elements are of variable witdh, the only way I can see this done is to dynamically get the width of the left and right divs via jQuery (or pure JavaScript, ask me for this version) and then adding the margin style to the centered div.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(setWidth);
function setWidth(){
var $left_width  = $(".left").width()  + 10;
var $right_width = $(".right").width() + 10;
$(".center").css("margin-left",$left_width + 'px');
$(".center").css("margin-right",$right_width + 'px');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">Variable width DIV</div>
    <div class="right">Another.</div>
    <div class="center">Centered Div</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{width:100%;}
.left{
float:left;
background-color:green;
}

.center{
text-align:center;
background-color:blue;
width:auto;
}

.right{
float:right;
background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle. Solution works with pure CSS.

The trick is: `width: 230px; /* 10 more width than column size */`

http://jsfiddle.net/ngdS9/1/